# How to make a drop down field (populated from mysql db) appear based on user selection

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a form. The first field is a drop down select option. The user will select the name of a company. Based on the name a second drop down select option needs to be generated showing the addresses of all the company's branches.

The company data is stored in a mysql database.

How can I make the above happen?

Comment: post your html code part

Comment: welcome ....Stackoverflow is not free code writing service/.. first give a try than if you have any problem than feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are saying about `<select>` tag, the you can use this.

```
<select name="option">
    <option value="one"<?php echo ($data["option"] == "one") ? ' selected="selected"' : ""; ?>>One</option>
    <option value="two"<?php echo ($data["option"] == "two") ? ' selected="selected"' : ""; ?>>Two</option>
    <option value="three"<?php echo ($data["option"] == "three") ? ' selected="selected"' : ""; ?>>Three</option>
</select>
```

---

#### For the sub select, see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ah4rx/

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here

1. post the form on change of first dropdown and fetch the data based on posted value and display.
2. use ajax functionality to fetch the data based on value selected in dropdown and display

Comment: could you help me perform the first option. I have been trying to find out how to go about that :-    `<label>Client Name</label><br>
   <select name="client_name">
    <?php
     $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM client");
     
     if($query1 === FALSE) {
      die(mysql_error()); 
     }
     echo "<option></option>";
     while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
     {
      
      echo "<option>".$row1['name']."</option>";
     }
    ?>
   <select>`   - this is the code through which the user selects the company name

Comment: I have figured out how to post the form on change using javascript. But then how should I modify my php file. Presently it takes all the data from form fields and generates a word document.

Comment: $cmpnydata = array(); if($_POST('fieldname') != ''){ //fetch company data here and assign to $cmpnydata }

Comment: my question is can this be done by the same php file that is called by action attribute? or should I have two separate forms - the first one submits onchange and fetches the data to be dispalyed. the second form  generates the word document.

Comment: you can keep one more form in that php file and a hidden field in that form, on change assign the dropdown value to hidden field and post that form. You can not give multiple actions to single form.

Answer (score 0):

As basic as it gets - Send the company name via ajax to php, query the database to get the address, populate the next drop down in the same php script whilst in the loop and echo out. Receive back in ajax

Answer (score 0):

I would use that code for the first generation of the first list. Then the second list would have to be done with AJAX ([JQUERY](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) can help you here). 
You want JQUERY to get

```
var client=$('#client_name').find("option:selected");
```

Then make a normal AJAX request.

I would recomend you to use a [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) to connect to your databse instead of using that generic connection.

Based on the code that you posted in the reply to Vamsi then the code would be

```
    <label>Client Name</label><br> 
    <select id="client_name"> 
    <?php
    // PDO connect to the DB
    $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB_NAME','DB_USER','DB_PASS');

    $sql = 'SELECT name FROM client'
    $result = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(count($results)>0){ echo "<option></option>";}

     foreach( $result as $key => $val)
     { 
// could also be $val['name'] depending on your db
echo "<option>".$key['name']."</option>"; 
} 

     ?>
     <select>
```